# Is the Berman-Hartmanis Conjecture Solved?

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, np-complete, one-way-functions

The Berman-Hartmanis conjecture more or less states that if one-way functions exist, there are some problems in $NP$ which cannot be polynomially reduced to $NP$-complete (cf. Ker-I Ko, A Note on One-Way Functions and Polynomial-Time Isomorphism).

Since the Cook-Levin theorem states that $NP$ is polynomial-time reducible to $NP$-complete.

Does the Berman-Hartmanis conjecture state anything about the converse statement? I.e. if $NP$ is polynomial-time isomorphic to $NP$, then one-way functions do not exist?

It seems to me that proving the converse and proving the non-existence of one-way functions proves the $P=NP$ problem.

Furthemore, is the Berman-Hartmanis conjecture solved?

Comment: Reading [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berman%E2%80%93Hartmanis_conjecture) I get a very different view of what the Berman-Hartmanis conjecture is. I think you might be confusing polynomial reduction and polynomial isomorphism.

Comment: I got my information mostly from: http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/manindra/isomorphism/easy-cylinder-conjecture.pdf and a paper by Ker-I-Ko... I may have overstated some things.

Answer (score 2):

The conjecture remains open. Also there is a proof that shows that if the conjecture is true, then P=/=NP. To my knowledge no one has proven the opposite, that if the converse is true then P=NP, to be true.

Comment: Do you have the link or a reference to the article that shows that if BH holds $P\neq NP$? thx.

Comment: Sparse complete sets for NP: Solution of a conjecture of Berman and Hartmanis (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000082900022 ) , basically it shows that if the conjecture is false, not the converse though, then P=NP, and the existence of the thing that proves the conjecture false is required for P=NP to be true.